# Is there a better GOKL map?

Tags: public-transport, kuala-lumpur

When preparing to travel to Kuala Lumpur I came across the GOKL city bus, which seems like a really good way to get around, sadly the map provided by them ( https://www.gokl.com.my/getting_around/index.html ) only shows their grid over a very faint street map, which doesn't seem to be aligned at all.

Does anyone know a better version of this map that lets you see the exact location of the bus stations on a street map?

Answer (score 1):

The map looks quite ok from the local way of looking at things. You may be expecting a bus service similar to wherever you are from. Definitely not a good idea in KL.
Before you go download the "Grabcar app". Use it or take a local taxi. Both are extremely cheap, even the roguish ones who will charge you triple. Beware the ones hanging around KL twin towers.
The only bus I would consider is the feeder bus going to and from the new MRT stations. Also, it is quite easy to grab a car and driver for a day if you plan to go out of KL a bit. Negotiate a price with a grab car or taxi. Genting Highlands or Melaka/Malacca town are recommended.
Also download 'Waze app' and Google maps and set offline areas to KL and Selangor. 
Recommendation by me is catch the MRT south to Kajang and get off almost to the southern end at restaurant called "Satay Kajang Haji Samuri" the unofficial world champion of satay. If you are from an affluent country then you will overeat on many different satay, drink and eat fresh coconut, drool over dessert named ABC and Cendol and come out feeling like you robbed them. 100 metres back to the MRT or just walk around town with a different feeling than KL.

Comment: You don't seem to be a fan of the bus, could you clarify why? That way I can understand why you don't want me to take the bus.

Comment: @ArthurAtlas Not the OP, but KL traffic is horrible and the bus system is poorly signposted and generally confusing.  Given how cheap the alternatives are, it's simply not worth the hassle if you're visiting as a tourist.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question.

Comment: @ajd Answering questions with "you're asking the wrong question" is a time-honored Travel.SE tradition, and often more useful for travellers than an actual answer.